# drawImage from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, drawimage

I'm trying to draw images from an array in such a loop:

```
var frames = [];
for(var i=0;i<assets.length;i++){
    frames[i] = new Image();
    frames[i].onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(frames[i],10,10);         
    };
frames[i].src = assets[i];
```

and get the error:

**Value could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement.**

I seems like the way "frames[i]" is passed to drawImage() is causing the problem.
Why is that so and what is the proper way to do it?
Is the variable "i" not valid in the context that the onload function is called?

Thanks

Comment: could you post other relevant code as well? First of all: what is in `assets`? How did you declare ctx? And please explain what you really try to accomplish. Now it looks like you are trying to draw on a canvas from an empty image. Which strikes me as odd :)

Comment: Why this will never work is because frames[i] is not available inside the anonymous function you are assigning to the onload event, that's another scope. But if you explain better what you are trying to do maybe we can offer you an alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `onload` callback is asynchronous, so when the callback function is called, the loop may have ended, and the `i` variable isn't defined anymore. Anyway, the `this` keyword point to the image inside the callback :

```
var frames = [];
for (var i=0; i<assets.length; i++) {
    frames[i] = new Image();
    frames[i].onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(this, 10, 10);         
    };
    frames[i].src = assets[i];
}
```

The next problem you'll may have is that you won't control in which order the images are drawn on the canvas. See this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8Gyw/).

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the following code:

```
var frames = [];
for (var i=0; i<assets.length; i++)
{
    frames[i] = new Image();
    frames[i].addEventListener(load, onImageLoaded, false);
    frames[i].src = assets[i];
}
function onImageLoaded(e)
{
    ctx.drawImage(this, 10, 10);
}
```

The rationale being that you dont need to maintain the variable `i`, also that it makes the code cleaner to read. Since the onImageLoaded handler function is attached in this manner, each time it's called, the `this` variable will hold what would have equated to `frames[i]`, where `i` holds the appropriate value.